# custom JavaScript(index.js) isn't working on my WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, wordpress

hi guys I'm building a WordPress website from scratch I'm trying to work on search bar but I found a problem when using JavaScript classes. i have a folder on my theme folder with name src (working with the folder build using node.js). in that folder i have another folder with name modules. i call the JavaScript files from modules using index.js (import example from ....). the custom JavaScript file is not working at all .i look at console no problem detected, i checked network the index.js is loading just fine but the JavaScript I'm writing is not working at all .

index.js :

```
import Search from "./modules/searchengine"

const search = new Search()
```

searchengine.js

```
import $ from "jquery"
class Search {

    constructor(){
        this.searchinput =  $(".search-submit") ;
    }
    events(){
        this.searchinput.on("click", this.typingLogic.bind(this));
        
    }
    typingLogic(){
        console.log("test")
    }
}
export default Search
```

function.php

```
function logistics_js_files()
{
    wp_register_script('main_scripts', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script('main_scripts');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'logistics_js_files');
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="widget widget_search">
 <div class="search-form">
    <label>
      <input class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" type="search">
    </label>
    <input class="search-submit" value="Search" type="button">
  </div>
</div>
```

i tried a lot nothing seems to work what do you think guys ?

Comment: well nothing is calling the event methods so why should they be run?

Comment: how can i make it run ?

Comment: add this.events(); to inside constructor

Comment: still not working the same problem. actually it was there i removed it while i was trying to figure out the problem. anyway thank you man

Comment: here is an example, its working just fine https://jsfiddle.net/0egsjynw/1/ otherwise make sure you've correctly set the script to modules etc to be able to import it and so on

Comment: i changed the code on functions.php instead of the line above i did wp_enqueue_script().

Comment: thank you mr breezer for your time i appreciate it <3